# modular v9 firestore getDocs await how to get to exception

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please look at following code, if await getDocs failed how to get to exception? This code currently will never get to exception.

```
try{
    const q = query(collection(firestoredb, "lists"), where("user", "==", "testID"));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    let data = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      data.push(doc.data());
    });

}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: What type of exception are you expecting the code to raise?

Comment: Just want it to go to exception when getDocs failed, lets say there is no internet

Comment: `getDocs()` will throw exceptions when a security rule rejects read or any error. If I block requests to Firestore domain then no exception is thrown but the querySnapshot is empty with `fromCache` set to true.

Comment: That's strange why would querySnapshot is empty but `fromCache` is true. According to [QuerySnapshot documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) there is no `fromCache` properties